# Web frontend plugin for AWS Elasticsearch service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-head

I am using AWS Elasticsearch service (ES version 5.3). What are the web frontend plugin that can be used with AWS-ES?

The [AWS ES supported plugins](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-plugins.html) doesn't seem to support any frontend view.

Also, doesn't seem like Elasticsearch-head plugin can't be installed inside the AWS-ES service. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use Kibana. Launch a local instance of it or running in ec2.

Or try cloud.elastic.co which has everything OOTB.

Disclaimer: I'm working at elastic.

Comment: To add on to this if you use AWS Elastic Search's Kibana solution, you will need to setup IP access if you plan to use it through a browser http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-troubleshooting.html#aes-troubleshooting-kibana-configure-anonymous-access